# handle derived property in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, javafx-8

I'm playing with JavaFX right now and I'm following a [tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/) to learn this sector of Java. I have a question about properties though:

**How to properly deal with derived property in JavaFX?**

Let me clarify with an example. Suppose you have a model with a simple property:

```
public class User {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday;
}
```

(I ignored the constructor and the property getters: suppose they are there) and suppose you have a view with a TableView with 2 columns listing users where:

- in the first column there is the name of the user;
- in the second column there is the **age** of the user;

Something like this (also displaying some paint skills!):

[image: View example]

Now, the age is of course a derived property of the birthday field and it can be easily implemented via the method:

```
public int getAge() {
    return Period.between(this.getBirthday().get(), LocalDate.now()).getYears();
}
```

However the table view won't accept an integer, but only an observable integer. I want the table to change automatically if someone changes the birthday of a user.

I could create a `SimpleIntegerProperty` inside the `setCellValueFactory` but I don't think that could be a solution. I could also create a `IntegerProperty` inside `User` class called `age` but it doesn't sound right to me because the age is a **derived property** from birthday.

So that arise my question: how to deal with derived property in JavaFX?

PS: I looked at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068378/how-to-implement-derived-read-only-properties-values-in-javafx) but, probably for my inexpertise in this field, I couldn't find it satisfactory.

Thanks for any kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the mentioned `setCellValueFactory` and `SimpleIntegerProperty`:

```
TableColumn<User, Integer> ageCol = new TableColumn<User, Integer>("Age");

ageCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
    SimpleIntegerProperty prop = new SimpleIntegerProperty(param.getValue().getAge());
    prop.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
        return param.getValue().getAge();
    }, param.getValue().birthday));
    return prop.asObject();
});
```

However, when you create the binding you use the following dependency `param.getValue().birthday` which is the mark that you know the inner calculation of the `getAge()` method (okay, for this case it's quite obvious that the calculation is based on the birthday, but there are some cases where it is not).

Therefore I would choose the second option that you mentioned to encapsulate the calculation to the place where it belongs: an additional (readonly) property in the `User` class, where the age is bound to the birthday.

```
public static class User {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday;

    private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper age;

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() { return birthday; }
    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty ageProperty() { return age.getReadOnlyProperty(); }

    private User(String name, LocalDate bDay) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(bDay);
        this.age = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
        age.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> Period.between(this.getBirthday(), LocalDate.now()).getYears(), birthday));
    }

    public String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public LocalDate getBirthday() { return birthday.get(); }
    public int getAge() { return ageProperty().get(); }
}
```

and then to use it:

```
TableColumn<User, Integer> ageCol = new TableColumn<User, Integer>("Age");
ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Integer>("age"));
```

The example uses the `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper` (from the answer you have linked) and exposes the inner property `age` via a `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty`:

```
public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty ageProperty() { return age.getReadOnlyProperty(); }
```

**Update:** The same `User` class using lazy-initialization on the `age` property.

```
public static class User {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday;

    private ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper age = null;

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() { return birthday; }

    public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty ageProperty() {
        if (age == null) {
            age = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();
            age.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> calculateAge(), birthday));
        }

        return age.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    private User(String name, LocalDate bDay) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(bDay);
    }

    public String getName() { return name.get(); }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {return birthday.get(); }

    public int getAge() {
        return (age != null) ? age.get() : calculateAge();
    }

    private final int calculateAge() {
        return Period.between(this.getBirthday(), LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is just too ugly: if I change the implementation I also need to change something in the UI controller; that sounds wrong to me. As for the second option... is it really the only available one? In JavaFX I am forced to disregard the concept of "derived property" and always "waste" space in memory to reference it? Is this the price we have to pay to be updated whenever we want?

Comment: For the first part: yes, that's what I mentioned:) For the second part: you could use lazy-init for `age` (do not create the property itself until it is not requested). But after a request you have to store the property (or a binding to `birthday') anyways, so it is better to store it in `User`.Maybe someone will come with a much nicer solution (anyways I will update the answer using lazy-init) :)

Comment: Thanks! It's not like I don't want to accept your answer; I'm just buffled that this is the only available solution: if a model class has few fields but lots of derived properties (like any non-anemic domain model) this solution will create a lot of boiler-plate code. I will wait some days before accepting this answer: if no one can come up with a cleaner solution, I will accept yours.

Comment: @James_D please clarify with an example. What may I achieve if I expose a `Binding` instead of `ReadOnlyProperty`? I can't see the difference

Comment: @DVarga after reading [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) I realized the method you posted is the official way to do what I wanted. Accepting the answer right now

Comment: @Koldar A read-only property stores the value. A binding simply knows how to compute the value and tracks when it should be recomputed.

Answer (score -1):

You could expose a `DoubleBinding` instead of a property for the age. A `DoubleBinding` is an implementation of `ObservableValue<Number>` (so it can be returned by the callback in a `cellValueFactory`), but unlike a `DoubleProperty` or `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty` it doesn't store its value internally:

```
public class User {

    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday ;

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() {
        return birthday ;
    }

    public final LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthdayProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        birthdayProperty().set(birthday);
    }

    private final DoubleBinding age = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
        () -> Period.between(this.getBirthday(), LocalDate.now()).getYears(),
        birthday);

    public DoubleBinding age() {
        return age ;
    }
}
```

You can then do things like

```
TableColumn<User, Number> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>(age);
ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().age());
```

Note this example isn't really ideal, because `age` can change value without `birthday` changing value (due to the irrepressible nature of the advance of time...). So to make this really accurate you might want to create an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate> today` somewhere, which updated on a daily basis. Then make your `age` binding update when it changed too

```
private final DoubleBinding age = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> Period.between(this.getBirthday(), LocalDate.now()).getYears(),
    birthday, today);
```

Though the original version is likely to be sufficient for most realistic use cases.